# pandas.core.index is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, future-warning

When running my Python code, I am getting the following general warning:

`pandas.core.index is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. The public classes are available in the top-level namespace.`

The error comes from the following package:
`/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anndata/core/anndata.py:17`

What does this error mean? And what do I need to change in order to resolve this?

Comment: What function return this warning?

Comment: `/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anndata/core/anndata.py:17`

Comment: I think problem is in package [anndata](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), is possible upgrade it?

Comment: Still there after upgrading, but for now no real problems.